# How to get arrays one at a time?

Tags: php, arrays

If someone access my page, I want to 'echo' the values inside my array one-by-one to them.

if first user access my page, php will get first array value and issue to it.

if second user access my page, php will get second array value and issue to it once again... and this process keeps so on!

User 1 > Number 1 | User 2 > Number 2 | User 3 > Number 1 | User 4 > Number 2.....

and for other I thing I want: 
*** if possible, to get first value more than the second.
For example: Number 1 viewed 8 times, number 2 viewed 4.

My simple array code:

```
$numbers = array(
            '+1111111111', // Number 1
            '+2222222222', // Number 2
);
```

Any help or suggestion, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is users authorised?

Comment: No, really simple stuff!

Answer (score 2):

PHP itself doesn't store any information between requests so I don't think there is a way of determining which user you are up to without using another technology.

To save a number to each user you can store them as a session variable, then when the user returns you can check if they've already been given a number before. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) might be a good place to start on sessions.

To give each new user a new number you'll most likely need to use a database to store all the previous values you've given to users, or simply store the index of the array that you are up to in your array in the database. The database will keep this information between different requests. I'm not sure of your level of expertise with PHP but databases are a slightly more advanced topic than session storage and may take some time to get up and running as you have to install them separately. The good news is that there are thousands of tutorials out there on them already.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to store any information, just choose an array at one time and other in another time, simple.

Comment: But if you want each user to have a different value then you need to know which values you've used before. That's what you're storing in the database. Right now, any time your PHP code runs, it doesn't know if it's given out 1 or 100 different values previously.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to use a mix of an alternating server stored variable, and then cookies to pass out to each user as they enter your site.

There are many ways to store a server side variable, and cookies are pretty straight forward.

My knowledge is limited, hopefully someone with more insight can help break down some details for you.

Comment: Controlling the odds of 1 vs 2 can been pretty easily achieved just using javascript Math.random()  This will roll you a number and you can set a condition to give option1 whenever the roll is less than 0.8 else option2

Comment: I don't want to store any information, just choose an array at one time and other in another time, simple

Comment: You are going to have to store that data somewhere.